im trying to install pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git into the command prompt but it does not work from whisper AI and im stuck
in whisper ai i am trying to put this code into command prompt pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git and it does not work it just tells me this  ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git version
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH? but the first thing install from whisper ai did work but i do not know what to.i have github installed and i have looked videos trying to solve this but it do not show how to solve. if yall could tell me a step by step solution i would appericate it because i do not have no experience to coding.
okay my bad so i do have git installed from windows not github and i did install pip install openai-whisper from whisper Ai into command prompt, the thing is just that it when i put this command pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git it says that there is an ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git version ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH? and im confused on what to do, am i supposed to have a file to called grit in pycharm so it can be directed there?
because this how your suppose to do right by steps to install it?
1.pip install -U openai-whisper
2.pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git
3. pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git

The project is named openai-whisper, why not install it from PyPI with the command pip install openai-whisper ?

If you gonna to install it from GitHub you really need Git in you $PATH. Install Git and check if it's in $PATH by running git --version .

okay my bad so i do have git installed windows not github and i did install pip install openai-whisper from whisper Ai into command prompt, the thing is just that it says there  ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git version
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH? and im confused on what to do, am i supposed to have a file to called grit in pycharm so it can be directed there?

If you're working from Anaconda, you'll need to install Git first. That is, first:
conda install git
And then, after installing Git:
pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git
A complete guide (for me) to the commands for installing whisper for Windows 11 in Anaconda as follows:
conda create --name whisper_env python=3.8
conda activate whisper_env
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.7 -c pytorch -c nvidia
conda install git
pip install git+https://github.com/openai/whisper.git
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg

You need to install git for windows which is different from GitHub (a website that stores git repositories).
You can install git for windows here: https://git-scm.com/download/win
Alternatively, why don't you try doing pip install -U openai-whisper instead? Like so: https://github.com/openai/whisper?tab=readme-ov-file#setup
